# SharedPreferences return nothing after app restart

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i save my token in Shared Preferences  with this Set Token method

```
public static void setToken(Context ctx, String token) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_TOKEN, token);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

and get token with this get Token method in all my project

```
public static String getToken(Context ctx) {
            return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_TOKEN, "456");
        }
```

my problem is when app is restarted, get Token method return "456"

home activity token log :

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjBkM2JlODBlMTg4Mzc4NTNjY2VjYjU2Nzg1NzAxYjNhM2NhZGJiOWFhYTZjYWIwNDQ3YjA4MzJmMzRkNmMxMzM5MzAyMWE2OWQ4NDk2ZTY1In0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMGQzYmU4MGUxODgzNzg1M2NjZWNiNTY3ODU3MDFiM2EzY2FkYmI5YWFhNmNhYjA0NDdiMDgzMmYzNGQ2YzEzMzkzMDIxYTY5ZDg0OTZlNjUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjAzMTY5MTQsIm5iZiI6MTU2MDMxNjkxNCwiZXhwIjoxNTkxOTM5MzE0LCJzdWIiOiI1Iiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.RovbkU1XXCuOcUvAzutW9Btm64BlYc8jAZTTeiPue43-YUMv2Ftr2m40I6yVH0JPdCGHwbtIruJRHeM8fx1ua4pryBQIxgdCvB-S5FiioOPR_zrG-II_pEquUQoz3wEpxmwG1KDmYOWfENA7El6v8e3mnyg54o9ikcYCFLgoV3V5kcdhX4RZRWeRE8ED76m1YhImjuIAkSV88tmtrzt1E7dWM_lfWDLGOsrPnOLFdzEGDozGHcMU6D5-qN9CroBGzrlLD4ngvk1yV1cypSLgsM9yuJ3b9MJJhcs5v_mrm5McT6aipcM6ghKdClGF7_SBAjREPJGxPD7-KY5sH4L9NkpsxH4SQL9fxKpE_Z2B_PCKVaCGtSBQ0E1dURFIkJfUWhFsRZea1DBXQkZTDcAnxj9WA2ZDqWe_Ve-fPDyhmnfObHfeJ0NRtm-Wgq6R-F5PwlF_SjxgrhXhKsAd4knvvkP-o06e_d3fb-8mUedmQQroI9VXci6kE5gJhqUWjX5OpCLWBCFY12Y5Vntg2R-G_sLPJXewkM7TcXlc381V212bJElFThgurWfm4zRfWA5L8VV8d_xms3f852rOg2z6xh0dNt5zeqp3b8IS68k1wTzBPGobJZSvr5ZDd_xZYpJREsDeLh8Osr7hP3V3zUWIMGdEyKUL3ITCL7FMAtj9VFA
```

After restart :

```
token=456
```

Comment: post full code how can you get `getSharedPreferences` using only context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple mistake, you have to replace this line

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
```

to below one

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Where KEY_PREFS_NAME is the name of your preference

Answer (score 0):

Try this to save it:

```
public void saveToken(String token){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, token).apply();
}
```

and this to get back:

```
public String getToken(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, "")
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why are you doing `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();` before returning the value? Also, don't you think calling `getSharedPreferences()` inside that `getToken()` method everytime you want to read from SharedPreference is a waste of resources? Please fix your code.